# does two ids are generated for session

Tags: asp.net

i have a Question on session in asp.net,  I am making an asp.Net application and i am using session for storing user_id and password. And i learnt that session is the particular time for which an user can interact with the application. I also learnt that i can use in precess, out process like state server and sql server for storing session. And when first time user hits the server then a uniqeId or token is stored on the user side in cookies form or if cookies are not enabled then munched URL is used for further communication with the server so i am confuse on pint that in my application i am taking userName in one session and password in one session and one more session for storing some value so i want to know that for each session i am using in application a unique id (token) is generated or one single token is generated corresponding to each user for that application even we are using any No. of session in that.

i want to ask something like this

```
session["userNme"]=userName;
session["password"]=password;
```

so i want to know when a user login then its user id and password is saved in session and on each page both user id and password is checked if session is expire then sent to login  page, so i want to know when user login does two tokens are generated one  for userId and one for password is it true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion comes from mixing up sessions and session variables.

What you are using is session variables, not sessions. There is only one session object for each user, and that object can contain several session variables.

As there is only one session object per user, there is only one session id per user.

The session objects are stored on the server (or on a state server) and the session id connects one user with one session object.

The session object has an Items collection that contains the session variables, and it's the variables in this collection that you are accessing when you put brackets after the session object.

So, your code is a shortcut for this:

```
Session.Items["userNme"] = userName;
Session.Items["password"] = password;
```

Comment: so session object is automaticaly rated when i use a single session item in the application is it correct i mean if i use session["userNmae"]=userName; session["password"]=password; then automatically an object of session is created is it true? Because i did not make any in my application ..

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: Each request always have a Session object (unless specifically declared as session-less). If you put session varaibles in the Session object it will be stored on the server, otherwise only the session is stored and a new Session object is created for each request.

Comment: Session[COMMON.SESSION_USERNAME.ToString()] = table.Rows[0][Student.studentColumns.user_name.ToString()].ToString();
            Session[COMMON.SESSION_USERID.ToString()] = table.Rows[0][Student.studentColumns.student_id.ToString()].ToString();

Comment: sir above is my code i am using in my project so now my confusion is clear as explained by you above now the queston is that i am just writing the session[] so is it creating some built in session objet using the system.web.sessionState name space because i never explicitally created any session

Comment: also sir one confusion how that unique is generated and sent to the client and does that unique id exist for the time until the session is expired? after that a new unique id will be created is it correct for new session

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: You don't have to create the Session object, it's created automatically. The unique id is created when the server session is created, and stored in a session cookie in the browser, so it survives on the client side until you close the browser. However, if the session times out on the server side, you will get a new session at the next request, and a new id.

Comment: i red that we can make persistent and non persistent cookie so if i make a persistent session cookie then if i close the browser and on server session is not expired yet..and then if i re open the browser can i again establish the session with cookie session id for further communication with the server for that particular client